# Promise not working properly when I use inside map using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise, feathersjs

I'm writing a JavaScript function for handling API calls inside map method, before done all tasks inside map method my function is to execute the wrong result. But it's not working for my expectation.

my code:

```
function vehicleAndWorker(hook){
  var routeArray = [];
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    hook.data.map(d => {
      var routeArray = [];
      delete d.driverId
      delete d.vehicle
      delete d.workers
      return hook.app.service('vehicles')
        .find({ query: {vehicleId: d.vehicleId}})
        .then(result=>{
          var vehicleTypeId = result.data[0].vehicleTypeId;
          return hook.app.service('vehicle-types')
              .find({ query: {vehicleTypeId: vehicleTypeId }})
              .then(result=>{
                  d.vehicle = {
                    vehicleId: d.vehicleId,
                    vehicleTypeId: vehicleTypeId,
                    fixedCost: result.data[0].fixedCost,
                    variableCost: result.data[0].variableCost
                  }
                  return hook.app.service('workers')
                    .find({ query: {assignedVehicleId: d.vehicleId}})
                    .then(result=>{
                        d.workers = [{
                          id:result.data[0].workerId,
                          name:result.data[0].name,
                          type:result.data[0].type
                        }];
                        delete d.vehicleId;
                  })
              })
          })
      })
      resolve(hook)
  })
}
```

before executing my map job, the return is executed how to resolve this.

Comment: Can you try placing **resolve(hook)** after **delete d.vehicleId;** ?

Comment: i tried its not working @KethaKavya

Comment: @SutarminAnton, you wrong

Comment: @2oppin, okay you are right. Checked in editor, it's just wrong indentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first chain your promises and not nest them .if you use nesting then you dont need promise.

second use promise all

```js
function vehicleAndWorker(hook){
    var all = [];
    var i =0;
    hook.data.map(d => {
      delete d.driverId
      delete d.vehicle
      delete d.workers
      all[i] = hook.app.service('vehicles')
        .find({ query: {vehicleId: d.vehicleId}})
        .then(result=>{
              var vehicleTypeId = result.data[0].vehicleTypeId;
              return hook.app.service('vehicle-types').find({ query: {vehicleTypeId: vehicleTypeId }})
         })
        .then(result=>{
            d.vehicle = {
              vehicleId: d.vehicleId,
              vehicleTypeId: vehicleTypeId,
              fixedCost: result.data[0].fixedCost,
              variableCost: result.data[0].variableCost
            }
            return hook.app.service('workers').find({ query: {assignedVehicleId: d.vehicleId}})
         })
        .then(result=>{
            d.workers = [{
              id:result.data[0].workerId,
              name:result.data[0].name,
              type:result.data[0].type
            }];
            delete d.vehicleId;
            return result
         })
          i++;
      })
     return Promise.all(all).then(hook);     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Your ".map" call returns a set of Promises. So it returns immidiatly,

```
function vehicleAndWorker(hook){
    var routeArray = [];
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) => 
       Promise.all(hook.data.map(d => {....})
          .then(() => resolve(hook))
    );
 }
```

As  @Akshay mentioned we can even reduce this function code, and move you "map" function in some other, so your vahicle will be single line:

```
var vehicleAndWorker = (hook) => Promise.all(hook.data.map(d => your_map_function)
              .then(() => hook);
```

Comment: I think, we can also do without return statement, that's what i did in my answer and move the resolve a line above

Comment: actually we can convert vehicleAndWorker(hoor) to single line, left so just to keep some similarity

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
function vehicleAndWorker(hook){
  var routeArray = [];
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    hook.data.map(d => {
      var routeArray = [];
      delete d.driverId
      delete d.vehicle
      delete d.workers
      hook.app.service('vehicles')
        .find({ query: {vehicleId: d.vehicleId}})
        .then(result=>{
          var vehicleTypeId = result.data[0].vehicleTypeId;
          hook.app.service('vehicle-types')
              .find({ query: {vehicleTypeId: vehicleTypeId }})
              .then(result=>{
                  d.vehicle = {
                    vehicleId: d.vehicleId,
                    vehicleTypeId: vehicleTypeId,
                    fixedCost: result.data[0].fixedCost,
                    variableCost: result.data[0].variableCost
                  }
                  hook.app.service('workers')
                    .find({ query: {assignedVehicleId: d.vehicleId}})
                    .then(result=>{
                        d.workers = [{
                          id:result.data[0].workerId,
                          name:result.data[0].name,
                          type:result.data[0].type
                        }];
                        delete d.vehicleId;
                  })
              })
          })
      resolve(hook)
      })
  })
}
```